# String com maior e menor número de caracteres

Tags: string, python-3.x

Desejo retornar a maior e a menor *string*.

Vejam:

```
nl=str(input('Digite uma string'))

String=[]
string.append(nl)

while caractere != 'pare':
    caractere = str(input("Digite uma letra ou número "))
    string.append(caractere)
```

Dentre as entradas que o usuário escrever, eu gostaria de pegar a maior e a menor *string* e imprimi-las na tela.

Comment: Mas o usuário irá entrar com uma letra, número ou um texto?

Comment: qualquer tipo de string, as strings de menor e maior caracteres seriam impressas. Ex:

23123
asd
da
as
.

A saída seria: 
menor  = .
maior = 23123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você criar uma lista, de forma bem semelhante ao que já fez:

```
textos = []
while True:
    texto = input("Entre com um texto:")
    if texto == 'pare':
        break
    textos.append(texto)
```

Depois, para encontrar o menor e maior texto, basta utilizar as funções nativas `min` e `max`, fazendo uso do parâmetro `key` passando a função `len`. Desta forma, você obterá o menor e maior texto em relação ao retorno da função `len` e não somente do conteúdo do texto.

```
menor = min(textos, key=len)
maior = max(textos, key=len)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, funcionou perfeito^^